# How to create a persistent bottom sheet in android

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

I want to create a persistent bottom sheet.

What I mean by persistent is that it can be collapsed and expanded.

Example: [GIF for persistent bottom sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbPcq.gif)

I've gone through the [Bottom sheet material docs](https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-sheets/overview) but couldn't find anywhere how i can replicate one, nor can I find any similar solution in stackoverflow.

All the examples/solutions I've seen seen are of one's which gets hidden completely when dismissed. But i wanted something which doesn't goes away completely.

How can I create this or something similar to this ?

I've gone through the [Bottom sheet material docs](https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-sheets/overview) but couldn't find anywhere how i can replicate one, nor can I find any similar solution in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Standard bottom sheet is a dialog Fragment so it's designed to no interact with the background view

Modal Bottom sheet is a View that allows you to interact with others views , so what you need to do is ,
these is **MainActivty.xml**  :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Hello world"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    <include layout="@layout/modal_bottom_sheet" />
 </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is your  **modal_bottom_sheet.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_rounded"
android:padding="@dimen/padding_16"
app:behavior_hideable="false"
app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior" > <!--  put your element here --> </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```